# If $f(x)=\sin^2(x)/x^6$, then does the integral for $f(x)$ from $0$ to $\infty$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, infinity

So, I was able to find that for $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ it converges to $\pi/2$, but for an expression more like the one I wrote, with the $x$ being raised to a higher exponent than the $\sin(x)$, I haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using bounds on $|\sin^2 x|$ and the $p$-test?

Comment: Clearly divergent.

Comment: @Gae.S. How so, because to me it looks clearly convergent since $$0\le f(x)\le 1/x^6.$$

Comment: @Allawonder I guess you are **mistakenly** convinced that $\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^6}\,dx<\infty$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Oops, I had been tacitly ignoring the limits since. That's true. This inequality doesn't tell us anything about the convergence of the integral since the lower limit is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

The integral
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x^m}dx
$$
with positive integer $m,n$ converges only if $n\ge m$. 
To see that the condition is necessary observe that the integrand behaves like $x^{n-m}$ in the vicinity of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for $0<x<\pi/3$,
$$
\sin x>\frac{x}{2}
$$
so
$$
\int_{\varepsilon}^{\pi/3}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^6}\,dx\ge\int_{\varepsilon}^{\pi/3}\frac{1}{4x^4}\,dx
$$
This decides for nonconvergence at 0.